# FlurryAgend.logEvent is logged on the Device but not Transmitted

Tags: android, flurry

I want to integrate `Flurry` as an analytics solution into my App. Initializing the session works just fine and the new sessions are shown in my dashboard.

However, my events are not. I am trying to log custom events as well as predefined ones, nut neither shows in my dashboard. A quick look into the app traffic confirms that no data transmission occurs on triggering `Agent.logEvent`.

The code I am using to log the event:

```
FlurryEvent.Params params = new FlurryEvent.Params()
                        .putDouble(FlurryEvent.Param.TOTAL_AMOUNT,34.99)
                        .putBoolean(FlurryEvent.Param.SUCCESS,true)
                        .putString(FlurryEvent.Param.ITEM_NAME,"book 1")
                        .putString(FlurryEvent.Param.ITEM_TYPE,"Book")
                        .putString("note","This is an awesome book to purchase!!!");
                FlurryEventRecordStatus status = FlurryAgent.logEvent(FlurryEvent.PURCHASED,params);
                Log.i("custom","the result of the event is: " + status.toString());
```

Logcat shows:

```
2023-09-25 17:35:34.293 29303-29303 FlurryAgent             de.tubs.cs.ias.flutebe               W  Log PURCHASED event - Missing recommended parameters: [fl.item.id, fl.currency.type, fl.item.count, fl.transaction.id]
2023-09-25 17:35:34.294 29303-29303 custom                  de.tubs.cs.ias.flutebe               I  the result of the event is: kFlurryEventRecorded
```

But my dashboard and the observed traffic remains empty. Based on the documentation, just callong `logEvent` should suffice but clearly I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event analytics data is not Real-time, only the Sessions data is. You will need to wait for few hours to one day to see the Event data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Do you have a source for this claim?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Po-Ting Wu seems to be correct. However, for testing purposes you can simply close the app and reopen it. This triggers the sending of the collected events prematurely.